# How to use mouse events with JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, mouseevent, javacv

I don't know how to use mouse events to control mouse actions on
javacv application.

I saw something but I'm confused!

Someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaCV displays images within regular Swing components, see for instance [Ex2MyFirstGUIApp](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/OpenCV2_Cookbook/src/opencv2_cookbook/chapter01/Ex2MyFirstGUIAppJava.java?repo=examples). You can use regular Swing mouse handling approaches.